# Google Sheets: How do send code to a blank cell?

Tags: google-sheets

If I have code written in cell A1 and cell B2 is blank, is there any function which will overwrite B2 with the contents of A1, but leave B2 blank if the function isn't enacted?

Or is there any other way to do this with Google Sheets?

Answer (score 3):

you can try this in B2 cell:

```
=A1
```

Comment: If I did that, then B2 wouldn't be blank.

Comment: @JamesGordonRoss can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?